# Sqlite3 multiple arguments in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sqlite

I'm new to sqlite3 but I'm starting to get the hang of it. I'm creating a simple command line based tool to remove entries from a database. The command I'm using works fine in interactive mode. It looks like this:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT computer_name FROM machine WHERE serial_number = "C02JT0XXXXXX";
MacBook01
```

But when I try to put it in a shell command it doesn't work:

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite "SELECT computer_name FROM machine WHERE serial_number = "C02JT0XXXXXX";"
Error: no such column: C02JT0XXXXXX
```

The weird thing is when I use a different argument is DOES work:

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite "SELECT computer_name FROM machine WHERE id = "1";"
MacBook01
```

It looks like if the second argument is longer than 1 character it fails. I tried a few others as well and they gave me the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, your first expression becomes `SELECT computer_name FROM machine WHERE serial_number = C02JT0XXXXXX;` -- effectively the quotes are stripped off.   This is OK for `id = 1` because that is a numerical comparison.  For the string `"C02JT0XXXXXX"` it causes problems.   Try single quotes:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite 'SELECT computer_name FROM machine WHERE serial_number = "C02JT0XXXXXX";'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already using those quotes.

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite 'SELECT computer_name FROM machine WHERE serial_number = "C02JT0XXXXXX";'

sqlite3 db.sqlite 'SELECT computer_name FROM machine WHERE serial_number = "'"C02JT0XXXXXX"'";'
```